# HTML Helper syntax issue

Tags: html-helper, razor-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have this piece of code in a couple of cshtml pages:

```
@model bt2.Models.ScheduleWork

@using System.Security.Claims;

@{
    bool Admin = User.IsInRole("Admin");
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    int Employee_ID = Int32.Parse(identity.FindFirst("DatabaseID").Value);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
```

If I understand correctly, I should be able to turn this into a html helper. But I can't find the correct syntax.

I have created a cshtml called `bthelper.cshtml` and placed it in the `App_Code` folder

This was my first try:

```
@helper GetUserInfo() {
// Load user info into sever side variables for subsequent use
// Admin (true if an admin user)
// Employee_Id 
@using System.Security.Claims;

@{    
        bool Admin = (User.IsInRole("Admin"));
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        int Employee_ID = Int32.Parse(identity.FindFirst("DatabaseID").Value);
    }
}
```

Then my view cshtml became

```
@model bt2.Models.ScheduleWork

@bthelper.GetUserInfo()

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
..........
....
```

When I run this I get

> > Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

With the highlight on the `@{` line in the helper

So I tried all the permutations below, all with error messages

```
@helper GetUserInfo() {

@using System.Security.Claims;

bool Admin = (User.IsInRole("Admin"));
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
int Employee_ID = Int32.Parse(identity.FindFirst("DatabaseID").Value);
}
```

> > Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "using" with "@".

Error on the `@using` line

```
@helper GetUserInfo() {

using System.Security.Claims;

bool Admin = (User.IsInRole("Admin"));
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
int Employee_ID = Int32.Parse(identity.FindFirst("DatabaseID").Value);
}
```

> > Namespace imports and type aliases cannot be placed within code blocks.  They must immediately follow an "@" character in markup.  It is recommended that you put them at the top of the page, as in the following example:
> >
> > @using System.Drawing;
> >     @{
> >       // OK here to use types from System.Drawing in the page
> >     }

Oh..... according to this my original syntax was actually correct

Can someone help me with the correct syntax? Razor syntax still confuses me. Contradictory error messages don't help